# "android:layout_margin" or "android:layout_marginTop"

Tags: android

I am writing a screen where I want put a vertical gap between two buttons:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show_cards"
            style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/show_cards" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_card"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size40dp"
            style="@style/btnStyleDark_khaki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add_card"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that there is no gap between buttons. But when I replace "android:layout_marginTop" with "android:layout_margin" then the gap is as I want. According to text I read "layout_marginTop" is the correct option. Any idea what I did worng?

Thanks,

zb

Comment: Could you check my answer please ?Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You have more answer for this scenario.As per your preference you can use

1.layout_margin_top="10dp" from second button

2.layout_margin_bottom="10dp" from first button

Answer (score 0):

Could you have `android:layout_margin="10dp"` code in your `btnStyleAcapulco` or `btnStyleDark_khaki` ?

If you use like this , `android:layout_marginBottom="40dp` or `android:layout_marginTop="40dp` will have no effect for your layout .

So you can check it . And remove `android:layout_margin="10dp"` code like this .

**The first way**

1.Add `android:layout_marginBottom="40dp""` to the Button `btn_show_cards` .

2.Add `android:layout_marginTop="40dp"` to the Button `btn_add_card` .

**The second way**

You can use `Space` for your code between two buttons .

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Second button only declare

```
android:layout_layout_marginTop=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match`
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_cards"
        style="@style/btnStyleAcapulco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/show_cards" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_card"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size40dp"
        style="@style/btnStyleDark_khaki"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_card" />
</LinearLayout>
```